# How To write query to get the output as shown below in my sql

Tags: mysql

**Bills table**

```
Bill_date   Total
28/10/13    10000
27/10/13    5000
```

**Payments table**

```
Paid_on    amount
28/10/13   5000
30/10/13   10000
```

**Expected output**

```
date        Credit    debit
27/10/13    5000    
28/10/13    10000     5000
30/10/13              10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.bill_date as `date`, t1.Total as Credit, t2.amount as debit  FROM Bills t1
LEFT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date= t2.Paid_on
UNION
SELECT t2.Paid_on as `date`, t1.Total as Credit, t2.amount as debit FROM Bills t1
Right JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date <> t2.Paid_on
UNION
SELECT t1.bill_date as `date`, t1.Total as Credit, t2.amount as debit  FROM Bills t1
LEFT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date <> t2.Paid_on
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.bill_date, sum(b.total), sum(p.amount)
from bills b full outer join payments p on b.bill_date=p.paid_on
group by b.bill_date
order by b.bill_date
```

You need the full outer join to get rows for days having bills but no payments and days having payments but no bills.

Comment: Note that you won't get rows with no bills and no payments.

Comment: Correct, that wasn't anywhere in the requirements.  If one row per day is required even if there were no bills AND no payments, then a calendar table will be needed to provide the dates to be reported.

Comment: With the given sample data,this query will return data only for the date `28/10/13`. It will not return any credit or debit data for the other dates

Comment: @BPRAM Thanks, I meant `full outer join` -- I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.bill_date, t1.total as Credit, t2.total as debit  FROM Bills t1
LEFT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date= t2.bill_date
UNION
SELECT t2.bill_date, t1.total as Credit, t2.total as debit FROM Bills t1
RIGHT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date= t2.bill_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like ,

```
SELECT t1.bill_date, t1.total AS Credit, t2.amount AS debit
FROM Bills t1
LEFT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date = t2.paid_on
UNION
SELECT t2.paid_on, t1.total AS Credit, t2.amount AS debit
FROM Bills t1
RIGHT JOIN Payments t2 ON t1.bill_date = t2.paid_on
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code.

```
  SELECT concat(`Bill_date`,' ',`Total`) FROM `tblname`
```